# Is it possible to read all files of the same format into one command in ffmpeg?

Tags: python, ffmpeg, concatenation

I have a python script which downloads a number of .ts and .aac files in the current working directory. I want to be able to concatenate them individually and then combine the final .ts and .aac files to produce the output.

Currently, I have around 90 files for both ts and aac. I understand it is possible to create a batch file containing the entirety of the related files which can be used to join them together, however, I wanted to find a solution that can ignore the creation of a batch file to increase the speed of the script.

Here is a basic interpretation of my request:

- 1.ts, 2.ts, 3.ts, 4.ts, 5.ts, 6.ts

  ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i 1.ts:6.ts -c copy output.ts

I've tried surfing the web for a solution, but all results lead me back to a batch file.
Any help is appreciated

Comment: Look at the `subprocess` module.

Comment: @BoarGules Yeah I'm currently using that to execute the command. Just want to know how I can concatenate all the files in the same line without creating a batch file.

Comment: See the concat protocol - http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html#concat

Comment: @Gyan Thanks, I think I got it working in a more trivial way, but just having issues with the output now.